# Generating a list of two-dim. points from list of higher-dim. ones

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table of lists, ie. `s = { {1, 2, 4}, {7, 11}, {3, 4, 12} }`. From this table, I would like to create the table of points `{ {1,1} , {1,2} , {1,4} , {2,7} , {2,11} , {3,3} , {3, 4} , {3, 12} }` where for each element $k$ of the $i$-th part of `s`, the point `{i,k}` is contained in the new table.

How can I do this? I am not experienced with Mathematica and only know how to use `Table`, `Select`, `Part`, etc. But those do not seem to work here.

Note: these were only examples; my actual `s` is much larger, so doing this manually is right out.

Comment: To understand how to do this, have a look at the doc page for [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up the answer step by step is sometimes useful. Especially if you might alter the procedure later. The pipeline below builds step by step from left to right. (`Range@Length@s` is same as `Range[Length[s]]`).  You have to understand `//` and short pure functions to understand the line below.

```
Riffle[Range@Length@s, s] // Partition[#, 2] & // Map[Thread, #] & // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

You can start just the part before the first // and then add steps sequentially to understand what is going on. That's how I developed it---from left to right.

So first

```
Riffle[Range@Length@s, s]
```

Then

```
 Riffle[Range@Length@s, s] // Partition[#, 2] &
```

And so on. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried both your method and the other answer's method, and used the other because it was more convenient. However, I still tried yours, and I learned a bit from your answer, so I will accept yours. I hope @Henrik Schumacher is OK with this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this way:

```
Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &, s]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 11}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 12}}

Just in case you actually want to assemble a `SparseArray` with `"AdjacencyLists"` given by `s`, you can do it like this:

```
A = With[{ci = Partition[Join @@ s, 1]},
   SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {Length[s], Max[s]}, 0., {1, {
       Prepend[Accumulate[Length /@ s], 0],
       ci
       }, ConstantArray[1, Length[ci]]}}
   ];

A["AdjacencyLists"] == s
A["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> True
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 11}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 12}}

(And no, this use of `SparseArray` is not documented.)

Comment: Your method was very useful; please see my comment on the accepted answer.